# Spring Context initialization failed with NoSuchMethodError on Heroku

Tags: java, spring, heroku, model-view-controller, deployment

I have deployed my Spring MVC application to Heroku. It's working fine locally, but won't run on Heroku and gives me an application error page. I checked the logs and this is what I see. I can't figure out how to solve the errors.

```
2016-11-29T15:15:00.658819+00:00 app[web.1]: Nov 29, 2016 3:15:00 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
2016-11-29T15:15:00.658847+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2016-11-29T15:15:00.731991+00:00 app[web.1]: Nov 29, 2016 3:15:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
2016-11-29T15:15:00.731995+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
2016-11-29T15:15:00.785546+00:00 app[web.1]: Nov 29, 2016 3:15:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
2016-11-29T15:15:00.785550+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2016-11-29T15:15:00.786501+00:00 app[web.1]: Nov 29, 2016 3:15:00 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
2016-11-29T15:15:00.786502+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
2016-11-29T15:15:01.022800+00:00 app[web.1]: Nov 29, 2016 3:15:01 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
2016-11-29T15:15:01.078904+00:00 app[web.1]: Nov 29, 2016 3:15:01 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
2016-11-29T15:15:01.022811+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Nov 29 15:15:01 UTC 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-11-29T15:15:01.078908+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]
2016-11-29T15:15:01.651920+00:00 app[web.1]: Nov 29, 2016 3:15:01 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
2016-11-29T15:15:01.726018+00:00 app[web.1]: Nov 29, 2016 3:15:01 PM org.springframework.security.core.SpringSecurityCoreVersion <clinit>
2016-11-29T15:15:01.651932+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
2016-11-29T15:15:01.726021+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: You are running with Spring Security Core 3.1.4.RELEASE
2016-11-29T15:15:01.726773+00:00 app[web.1]: Nov 29, 2016 3:15:01 PM org.springframework.security.core.SpringSecurityCoreVersion <clinit>
2016-11-29T15:15:01.726775+00:00 app[web.1]: SEVERE: *** Spring Major version '3' expected, but you are running with version: 4.1.4.RELEASE. Please check your classpath for unwanted jar files.
2016-11-29T15:15:01.727522+00:00 app[web.1]: Nov 29, 2016 3:15:01 PM org.springframework.security.config.SecurityNamespaceHandler <init>
2016-11-29T15:15:01.727524+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Spring Security 'config' module version is 3.1.4.RELEASE
2016-11-29T15:15:01.952894+00:00 app[web.1]: Nov 29, 2016 3:15:01 PM org.springframework.security.config.http.HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser checkFilterChainOrder
2016-11-29T15:15:01.952905+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Checking sorted filter chain: [Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 200, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 400, <org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0>, order = 800, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1200, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1300, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1400, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1700, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1800, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1900, <org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0>, order = 2000]
2016-11-29T15:15:02.986085+00:00 app[web.1]: Nov 29, 2016 3:15:02 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
2016-11-29T15:15:02.986094+00:00 app[web.1]: SEVERE: Context initialization failed
2016-11-29T15:15:02.986095+00:00 app[web.1]: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.clearCache()V
2016-11-29T15:15:02.986096+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.resetCommonCaches(AbstractApplicationContext.java:906)
2016-11-29T15:15:02.986097+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:567)
2016-11-29T15:15:02.986098+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
2016-11-29T15:15:02.986099+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
2016-11-29T15:15:02.986100+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
2016-11-29T15:15:02.986100+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4812)
2016-11-29T15:15:02.986101+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255)
2016-11-29T15:15:02.986102+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
2016-11-29T15:15:02.986103+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
2016-11-29T15:15:02.986103+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
2016-11-29T15:15:02.986105+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2016-11-29T15:15:02.986105+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
2016-11-29T15:15:02.986106+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
2016-11-29T15:15:02.986107+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-11-29T15:15:02.986108+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-11-29T15:15:02.986963+00:00 app[web.1]: Nov 29, 2016 3:15:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
2016-11-29T15:15:02.986965+00:00 app[web.1]: SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
2016-11-29T15:15:02.986966+00:00 app[web.1]: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.clearCache()V
2016-11-29T15:15:02.986967+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.resetCommonCaches(AbstractApplicationContext.java:906)
2016-11-29T15:15:02.986968+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:567)
2016-11-29T15:15:02.986968+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
2016-11-29T15:15:02.986969+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
2016-11-29T15:15:02.986970+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
2016-11-29T15:15:02.986971+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4812)
2016-11-29T15:15:02.986971+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255)
2016-11-29T15:15:02.986972+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
2016-11-29T15:15:02.986973+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
2016-11-29T15:15:02.986987+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
2016-11-29T15:15:02.986989+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2016-11-29T15:15:02.986990+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
2016-11-29T15:15:02.986990+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
2016-11-29T15:15:02.986995+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-11-29T15:15:02.986996+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-11-29T15:15:02.987555+00:00 app[web.1]: Nov 29, 2016 3:15:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
2016-11-29T15:15:02.987557+00:00 app[web.1]: SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
2016-11-29T15:15:03.001111+00:00 app[web.1]: Nov 29, 2016 3:15:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
2016-11-29T15:15:03.001114+00:00 app[web.1]: SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
2016-11-29T15:15:03.004786+00:00 app[web.1]: SEVERE: Context [] failed in [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] lifecycle. Allowing Tomcat to shutdown.
2016-11-29T15:15:03.006237+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2016-11-29T15:15:03.006234+00:00 app[web.1]: Nov 29, 2016 3:15:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
2016-11-29T15:15:03.006887+00:00 app[web.1]: Nov 29, 2016 3:15:03 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext doClose
2016-11-29T15:15:03.006889+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Nov 29 15:15:01 UTC 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-11-29T15:15:03.009660+00:00 app[web.1]: Nov 29, 2016 3:15:03 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext doClose
2016-11-29T15:15:03.009662+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING: Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
2016-11-29T15:15:03.009665+00:00 app[web.1]: java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Nov 29 15:15:01 UTC 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-11-29T15:15:03.009666+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:417)
2016-11-29T15:15:03.009666+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1002)
2016-11-29T15:15:03.009667+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:961)
2016-11-29T15:15:03.009668+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:581)
2016-11-29T15:15:03.009668+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:116)
2016-11-29T15:15:03.009683+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4859)
2016-11-29T15:15:03.009684+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5478)
2016-11-29T15:15:03.009685+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
2016-11-29T15:15:03.009686+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
2016-11-29T15:15:03.009686+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
2016-11-29T15:15:03.009687+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
2016-11-29T15:15:03.009688+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2016-11-29T15:15:03.009689+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
2016-11-29T15:15:03.009689+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
2016-11-29T15:15:03.009690+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-11-29T15:15:03.009691+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

here's my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.adamsashburneducation</groupId>
    <artifactId>adamsashburneducation</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- =====================
            1. Spring Web MVC
        ====================== -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ================================
            3. Spring Core and Spring ORM
        ================================= -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ======
            2. JSTL
        ======= -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ============
            4. Hibernate
        ============= -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- =============
            5. H2 Database
        ============== -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.192</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- =============
            MySQL
        ============== -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.34</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ===================
            6. Image File Upload
        ==================== -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ============
            7. Validation
        ============= -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- =================
            8. Spring Security
        ================== -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <finalName>adamsashburnedu</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals><goal>copy</goal></goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                    <version>8.0.30.2</version>
                                    <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

list of libs that I have in my lib folder:

```
aopalliance-1.0.jar
commons-logging-1.2.jar
spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-aspects-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-instrument-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-instrument-tomcat-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-jms-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-messaging-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-oxm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-test-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-portlet-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-websocket-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar
```

Comment: Show us your code. Looks like incompatible dependency.

Comment: Suraj, please see my comment below.

Comment: please add that as an edit to your question. That's not comments section, you've posted an answer. Delete it and add it to your question.

Comment: Thank you once again for letting me know that. I have updated my question as suggested.

Comment: Can you try with spring version 4.2.5.RELEASE? Also, check your classpath and make sure that it's picking the right spring versions. Check if you have any duplicate jars.

Comment: @SurajBajaj - Thank you so much! I had duplicate jars and my classpath was messed up which has been fixed now and the app is running on heroku perfectly fine.

Comment: Cool! I've added that as an answer, you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.clearCache()V`

This probably means you have **incompatible dependencies**.

You can try these things:

- Check your pom to make sure you have all compatible dependencies.
- Check your classpath and verify the right jars are being referenced.
- Check your classpath for any duplicate jars.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same exact issue in heroku. The problem was not related to my code or application related configuring file (including pom.xml). Because my application was working fine, and all of the sudden I saw the container crash and when I tried to start it, I kept getting the error described in this thread. After 24 hours or so, tomcat started working again on its own, without me changing anything in my code or pom.xml. So, while I don't know the root cause of the issue, I know it was not something that I had done. It was something environment related.